# How to upload a pdf from iphone using phonegap?

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, cordova, upload

I was able to upload images present in my imagegallery using the phonegap application. 
I want to know whether it will be possible for me to upload a pdf from the iphone application. Either using phonegap OR any native technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a `<input type="file">` field and send the form against a script where you can work with it?

[Perhaps this will lend you in the right way](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).